# Loop through columns PSQL

Tags: psql

I want to loop through each column and increment the counter if the value isn't NULL for any column. So if there are three columns out of 7 in a row with values not null then the counter value should be 3.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow ! Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loops are slow if you can avoid them. If you know the names of the columns, you can do something like this:

```
UPDATE table SET counter = 
  CASE WHEN colA IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END +
  CASE WHEN colB IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END +
  CASE WHEN colC IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END +
  CASE WHEN colD IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END +
  CASE WHEN colE IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END +
  CASE WHEN colG IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END +
  CASE WHEN colF IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END;
```